# Remove all changes after reboot

Tags: debian, filesystems, tmpfs

I want to allow users to be able to make temporary changes such as create files and directories, but have all those changes removed after rebooting. This should apply to everywhere in the file system.

I've tried reading up on `tmpfs`, but I'm unsure if there's better solutions.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

My distribution is debian (newest version).

Comment: Are you talking about root (`/`)? Maybe [overlayroot](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/overlayroot) is what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes root (```/```) is correct. I'll take a look at overlayroot, thanks!

Comment: You might find Fedora Silverblue or Kinoite are better start points to achieve what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This should apply to everywhere in the file system.

Suppose the filesystem is `/home`.

Create a `/home_template` filesystem,
and `rsync` from it to the destination upon booting up:

```
rsync -a --delete /home_template /home
```

---

EDIT

> Can this also be done for /, the whole file system?

Well, `/` slash is emphatically not *everything*.
It is a single filesystem,
and under it we might find things like
`/var` and `/run` mounted.

Use tools like

- `find -x`
- `du -x`
- `rsync -x`

to avoid leaving that filesystem
during a recursive traversal.

Doing either of these operations sounds dangerous:

- rsync -x -a --delete /slash_template /
- rsync -x -a --delete /usr_template /usr

Try them out and
[report back](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
on how it goes.
The `rsync --files-from` option
lets you specify a long list of files,
such as `find` produces.
You might want to `diff` lists
of files as part of a dry run,
or to determine which files
a script should `rm`.

You'd probably be better off defining
three partitions, {template, A, B},
and then creating a ghost image
by `dd`ing from template to A or B,
the one that's not active ATM.
Then boot from the newly copied A or B.

All of this begs the question:
Why aren't you just booting up
a Dockerized container?
It is the perfect way to express the
desire to "freeze" an image,
run while it mutates,
then boot up a new instance
which has exactly those same frozen bits.

Comment: Can this also be done for ```/```, the whole file system?

Comment: (in case the user uses sudo to install something in ie /etc or /usr)

Comment: You are right - I'll run a container and just re-running it after booting. Thanks!